# Perché lo chiamiamo fon?

Tags: etymology

L'asciugacapelli viene comunemente chiamato fon. L'origine sembra essere tedesca, ma perché questo termine è usato per indicare un asciugacapelli?

[Asciugacapelli](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/asciugacapelli/) (Treccani):

> - Apparecchio elettrodomestico, comunem. chiamato fon (forma italianizzata del ted. Föhn), che asciuga in breve tempo i capelli bagnati, convogliando su questi una massa d’aria, per lo più calda.

[Asciugacapelli](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asciugacapelli) (Wikipedia):

> - (colloquialmente chiamato fon o fohn /fɔn/, ma spesso riportato, meno giustificatamente, nella variante grafica phon) è un piccolo elettrodomestico che genera un getto di aria calda allo scopo di asciugare i capelli, ossia disperdere l'umidità in essi contenuta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il nome viene dal tipo di vento caldo e secco chiamato in tedesco *Föhn*, tipico dell'Europa continentale (vedi [Wikipedia inglese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foehn_wind) o [italiana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favonio)). La parola viene a sua volta dal latino *favonius*, che indicava un vento e la sua personificazione come divinità; in italiano si chiama anche, appunto, [favonio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/favonio/).

Quanto a perché fu scelto proprio questo nome, deriva dal marchio registrato “Fön” (senza “h”, per richiamare il nome del vento ma avere una parola depositabile) con cui la ditta Sanitas commercializzò nel 1908 i suoi primi asciugacapelli, marchio poi acquisito dalla AEG. (Vedi [Wikipedia tedesca](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haartrockner) e altri siti tedescofoni.)

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, in realtà la mia domanda , forse non sufficientemente chiara, e' sul perché fon viene usato per indicare un asciugacapelli. Una pubblicità? I primi fon erano tedeschi e in Germania li chiamano così? O altro?

Comment: @Josh61: Ah, non avevo capito: ho aggiunto qualcosa in proposito.

Comment: @Josh61 In tedesco "fon" è *Haartrockner*, cioè *asciugacapelli*. Che esiste anche in italiano, solo che l'asciugacapelli per eccellenza è il "fon" (una metonimia, la marca per l'oggetto. Come "Scottex" per la carta asciugatutto). Anche in Germania si può dire [Fön](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haartrockner)!
Lo spelling più comune e improprio, comunque, è "phon" e non "fon" o "fohn"